# Combine multiple fields when searching in REACT

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have 3 search fields like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMDRC.png)

I have combined 2 first fields when searching but I don't know how to combine the last one.
Here is my code to combine 2 first fields:

```
import React from 'react';
import Nav from '../components/Nav';
import FixedNav2 from '../components/FixedNav2';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import '../styles/style.scss';
import RatedRecipeItem from '../components/RatedRecipeItem';

class Recipe extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            recipes: [],
            // filterList:{
                category: "",
                cuisine:"",
                sort:"",
            // },
            dataIsReturned :false
        }
        this.handleChangeCategory = this.handleChangeCategory.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeCuisine = this.handleChangeCuisine.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeSort = this.handleChangeSort.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    async componentDidMount(){
        const pathname = 'http://localhost:4000/recipes/';
        const data = await fetch(pathname);
        const recipes = await data.json();
        recipes.forEach(recipe => {
            const newDate = new Date(recipe.date);
            const day = newDate.getDate();
            const month = newDate.getMonth()+1;
            const year = newDate.getFullYear();
            recipe.date = day+'-'+month+'-'+year;
        });
        this.setState({
            recipes:recipes,
            dataIsReturned:true
        })  
    }
    handleChangeCategory(event){
        this.setState({category:event.target.value })
    }
    handleChangeCuisine(event){
        this.setState({cuisine:event.target.value })
    }
    handleChangeSort(event){
        this.setState({sort:event.target.value })
    }
    handleSubmit(event){

    }
    getUnique(arr, comp) {

        // store the comparison  values in array
        const unique =  arr.map(e => e[comp])

        // store the indexes of the unique objects
        .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)

        // eliminate the false indexes & return unique objects
        .filter((e) => arr[e]).map(e => arr[e]);

        return unique;
    }
    
    render() {
        const recipes = this.state.recipes;
        const dataIsReturned = this.state.dataIsReturned;
        if(!dataIsReturned){
            return <div>LOADING...</div>
        }
        const uniqueCategory = this.getUnique(recipes,"category");
        const uniqueCuisine = this.getUnique(recipes,"cuisine");
        const category = this.state.category;
        const cuisine = this.state.cuisine;
        const sort = this.state.sort;
        console.log(category,cuisine,sort);
        // console.log(cuisine === "");
        // console.log(uniqueCategory);
        
        const filterRecipes = recipes.filter(function(recipe) {
            // console.log(recipe.category)
            if(cuisine && category)
                return recipe.category === category && recipe.cuisine === cuisine
            else if(!cuisine && category)
                return recipe.category === category
            else if(cuisine && !category)
                return recipe.cuisine === cuisine
            else return []
        });
        console.log(filterRecipes);
        return(
            <section className="recipe-section">
                <Nav/>
                <FixedNav2/>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="search">
                        <div className="search__content">
                            <form className="flex flex-jc-sb" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                <div className="search__group flex">
                                    <label for="recipe-category">
                                        Recipe Category
                                    </label>
                                    <select className="recipe-select" value={this.state.category} onChange={this.handleChangeCategory}>
                                        <option selected> - Select - </option>
                                        {uniqueCategory.map(recipe => 
                                            <option key={recipe._id} value={recipe.category}>
                                                {recipe.category}
                                            </option>
                                        )}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className="search__group flex">
                                    <label for="recipe-category">
                                        Recipe Cuisine
                                    </label>
                                    <select className="recipe-select" value={this.state.cuisine} onChange={this.handleChangeCuisine}>
                                        <option selected> - Select - </option>
                                        {uniqueCuisine.map(recipe => 
                                            <option key={recipe._id} value={recipe.cuisine}>
                                                {recipe.cuisine}
                                            </option>
                                        )}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className="search__group flex">
                                    <label for="recipe-category">
                                        Sort recipes
                                    </label>
                                    <select className="recipe-select" value={this.state.sort} onChange={this.handleChangeSort}>
                                        <option selected> - Select - </option>
                                        <option value="Top rated">
                                            Top rated
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="Latest">
                                            Latest
                                        </option>
                                        <option value="Most favourited">
                                            Most favourited
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div className="search__group">
                                    <input type="Submit" value="Search for recipes"/>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div className="recipe-list flex flex-jc-sb flex-ai-c">
                    {
                    (filterRecipes.length !== 0) ?
                        filterRecipes.map(recipe => 
                            <RatedRecipeItem recipeID={recipe._id} images={recipe.image} 
                            authorID={recipe.user._id} date={recipe.date}
                            avatars={recipe.user.avatar} authorsName={recipe.user.fullname} 
                            foodTitles={recipe.title} foodDescriptions={recipe.description} 
                            difficulty={recipe.difficulty} yeild={recipe.yeild} 
                            numOfPeople={recipe.numOfPeople} times={recipe.times}
                            cuisine={recipe.cuisine} category={recipe.category}
                            ingredients={recipe.ingredients} steps={recipe.steps}/>
                        )
                        :( (category !== "" || cuisine !== "") ? <div>There is no recipe you want to find.</div>
                            :   recipes.map(recipe => 
                                <RatedRecipeItem recipeID={recipe._id} images={recipe.image} 
                                authorID={recipe.user._id} date={recipe.date}
                                avatars={recipe.user.avatar} authorsName={recipe.user.fullname} 
                                foodTitles={recipe.title} foodDescriptions={recipe.description} 
                                difficulty={recipe.difficulty} yeild={recipe.yeild} 
                                numOfPeople={recipe.numOfPeople} times={recipe.times}
                                cuisine={recipe.cuisine} category={recipe.category}
                                ingredients={recipe.ingredients} steps={recipe.steps}/>
                                )
                        )
                    }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Footer/>
            </section>
        )
    }
}

export default Recipe;
```

In this code above, I get cuisine and category from option that users select and declare variable filterRecipes to store the result after filtering. The last option includes: Top Rated(numOfLike), Most Favourited(numOfFavourited) and Latest(date): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Cd0.png) which means I have to sort my recipes array and combined with 2 first fields. Anyone can help me to solve this problem?
Here is my structure of a recipe

```
category: "Desert"
cuisine: "Italia"
date: "22-4-2021"
description: "Pizza, dish of Italian origin consisting of a flattened disk of bread dough topped with some combination of olive oil, oregano, tomato, olives, mozzarella or other cheese, and many other ingredients, baked quickly"
difficulty: "Medium"
image: "https://www.recipe30.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/fried-pizza-848x477.jpg"
ingredients: (4) ["Egg", "Bread", "Milk", "Tomato"]
numOfFavourited: 5
numOfLike: 3
numOfPeople: "5 people"
steps: (7) ["Preheat pizza stone (or pizza pan or baking sheet):", "Divide the dough into two balls:", "Prep toppings:", "Flatten dough ball, and stretch out into a round:", "Brush dough top with olive oil: ", "Sprinkle pizza peel with corn meal, put flattened dough on top", "Spread with tomato sauce and sprinkle with toppings:"]
times: "1 hour"
title: "Pizza"
user: {favouritedRecipes: Array(0), recipes: Array(0), numOfLike: 4, _id: "608150e51553791e9486bb8c", fullname: "Do Quang Huy", …}
yeild: "A pack"
__v: 0
_id: "6081513899b23b41bca9b605"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you want to do something like this:

```
const filterRecipes = recipes.filter(r => {
    if (cuisine && r.cuisine !== cuisine) return false;
    if (category && r.category !== category) return false;
    return true;
} )

const sorted = filterRecipes.sort((a, b) => b.numOfLike - a.numOfLike)
```

Comment: tks, but what I mean here is how I can sort my recipes array( For example: sort from most number of like to least, from most number of favourited to least) and combine with 2 fields: cuisine and category.

Comment: When you say you want to combine two fields, can you explain what you mean a little more? For example, do you mean you want to filter those two, then sort by likes?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I want to filter recipes array by 2 fields: category and cuisine, then for example: if user select option "Top rated", I will sort by likes.